# django queryset values() to string or json

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to convert my dict to a list of string.
this is what generated by django froms
[list of student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZITUu.png)

I want to have a list without the {''}
My forms :

```
    students= ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
    attrs={'class': 'displaynone'}),
    queryset=Student.objects.exclude(present=True).order_by(
        'name').values('name'),
    required=False,
    label="Choice Students"
)
```

and template

```
{% for i in form.students %}
  {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

and I know I can juste do `queryset=Student.objects.exclude(present=True).order_by('name')`
without the values() but I juste want to retreive the name. It will optimize the load of my page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#only) to specify certain fields you want to fetch from the database, if you subsequently access a field that was not included in `only()` this will then cause a query to be run

```
queryset=Student.objects.exclude(present=True).order_by('name').only('name', 'id')
```

Comment: @rixemo2349 can you add the rest of the template to your question? What is the `get_classes` filter?

Comment: I did just at the top.

Answer (score 0):

yeah it's working well, but my load is the same. I think its because i also retreive the classes in my template.
like

```
<td class="class-name">{% for j in i.data.value|get_classes %}{{ j }}<br/>{% endfor %}</td>
```

and I use custom tags to retreive classes

```
def get_classes(student):
mystudent = Student.objects.get(pk=student)
list_student = list()
for i in mystudent.classe_set.all():
    list_student.append(i.name)
return list_student
```

Comment: You call the `get_classes` tag on every student in the queryset and this executes a bunch of queries, this seems to be your actual issue? Can you add the full template section where you render the choices?

Answer (score 0):

this is my template.

```
<table class="table" id="student_table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Student(s)</th>
        <th scope="col">Classe(s)</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
{% for i in form.student %}
    <tr class="click_student">
        <td>{{ i}}</td>
        <td class="schedule-name">{% for j in i.data.value|get_classes %}{{ j }}<br/>{% endfor %}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and this what it's look like.
[image: student with their classes]

there is a relationship between student and class.